# Splitting static files in my webpage - What are the trade-offs?

Tags: django, performance, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap, styles

I am currently involved in a Django project and I am definitely using Twiter bootstrap for the layout.

Though not actually precise, my question is quite simple: Bootstrap allows me to choose which styles/JS I want to download separately -- forms, tables, responsive, styles for buttons, navigation, etc -- and also together in a single "all-inclusive" file.... and I am not using all the resources at once on the same page.

Additional to that, we have the Django template system, which allows me to build one template over another, so I can basically add the more general stuff to my base template and, as I need in subtemplates, include the other static files.

So, to sum up everything: **Is it worth it, to have those styles separated?** I think that in terms of organization maybe it is not so clean, because I will have to import and handle more CSS files, but on the other hand I won't be loading unnecessary stuff.

What are the trade-offs of this choice?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it worth it, to have those styles separated

No it is not. If you look around, e.g. [visitmix](http://visitmix.com/opinions/to-minify-or-not-to-minify), you'll see that the overhead of requestig new files make the difference neglible.

Server you static from a cookie-less domain and you'll users will only have to hit your servers twice: once for CSS and once for JavaScript.

Comment: I agree completely. It would only be worthwhile to strip out parts of Bootstrap is you'll *never* use those parts. If you'll use them at all anywhere at anytime, just roll the whole CSS/JS.